# Interpretaion Of ordinal logistic regression

Tags: statistical-significance, categorical-data, linear, ordinal-data

I have one variable overall_sentiment with (Positive, Negative, Neutral) three levels. I have one more variable comments_created_at with (Monday, Tuesday,  Wed, Thu, Fri, sat, sun) 7 levels. I have to find the relationship between sentiment and days of the week. I have fitted below the ordinal regression model. Can anyone help me to interpret this result? Or any other way to perform this kind of analysis.

````
Call:
polr(formula = overall_sentiment ~ comments_created_at, data = Meteor, 
    Hess = TRUE)

Coefficients:
                           Value Std. Error t value
comments_created_atMon -0.008606    0.03981 -0.2162
comments_created_atSat -0.091378    0.04950 -1.8460
comments_created_atSun -0.189184    0.05357 -3.5315
comments_created_atThu -0.016743    0.03864 -0.4334
comments_created_atTue  0.101762    0.03608  2.8206
comments_created_atWed  0.022987    0.03724  0.6173

Intercepts:
                 Value    Std. Error t value 
negative|neutral  -1.2325   0.0289   -42.7141
neutral|positive  -0.0855   0.0279    -3.0695

Residual Deviance: 62299.23 
AIC: 62315.23
```
````

Comment: It depends what you are trying to accomplish...  For me, I like to see an anova-like table and post-hoc comparisons.  you can use *[Anova](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/car/versions/3.0-3/topics/Anova)* from the *car* package. From there, you can use *[emmeans](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/emmeans/versions/1.4.1/topics/emmeans)* to compare among the days of the week.